# Edição inline vuejs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, vue.js

Quando fazer click na coluna nota todas as inputs aparecera  mostrado. Queria que cada input aparecera quando for clicada na linha correspondente.

```js
 new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {

        nota:'nota',
        edit: '',
        myclass: 'before',
        pincel: 'before',
        list: [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "Firstname": "Humberto",
                "Lastname": "Lopes",
                "Email": "hrtlopes@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx"

            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Firstname": "Luis Humberto",
                "Lastname": "Lopes",
                "Email": "luis@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx"

            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "Firstname": "Lino",
                "Lastname": "Moniz",
                "Email": "Linovaz@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx"

            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "Firstname": "Jorge",
                "Lastname": "Cabral",
                "Email": "liljorge@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx"
            }
        ],            
        
      },
      methods: {

        whenclick(item) {  

        console.log(item);        
          this.edit = true;     
         },
         whenedited(nota) {
                     
          this.nota = nota;
          this.edit = false;
                 

         },
        
    change() {
      console.log('rato em cima');
      this.myclass = 'after';
      this.pincel = 'after';
    }
       
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="container">

    <div id="title"style="text-align:center;rgb(180, 67, 67);">
        <h3>Inline edition </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="caixa"style="margin:0 auto;">
 

  <!--  <span v-show="!edit" @click="whenclick()" :class="pincel" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
         


         <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                  <tr>  
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Apelido</th>
                      <th>Email</th>  
                      <th>Nota</th>                                  
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(item, index) in list">                      
                      <td>{{item.Firstname}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Lastname}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Email}}</td> 
                      <td>

                      <span v-if="!edit" :class="myclass"  v-on:mouseover= "change()"  @click="whenclick(item)">{{item.Nota}} </span>

                      <input  v-model="item.Nota" v-on:keyup.enter="whenedited(item.Nota)" v-on:blur="whenedited(item.Nota)" v-if="edit" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder=""> 

                      


                      </td>                                  
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>   

  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei isto abaixo:

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {

        nota:'nota',
        edit: '',
        myclass: 'before',
        pincel: 'before',
        list: [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "Firstname": "Humberto",
                "Lastname": "Lopes",
                "Email": "hrtlopes@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx",
                Editable: false

            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Firstname": "Luis Humberto",
                "Lastname": "Lopes",
                "Email": "luis@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx",
                Editable: false

            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "Firstname": "Lino",
                "Lastname": "Moniz",
                "Email": "Linovaz@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx",
                Editable: false

            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "Firstname": "Jorge",
                "Lastname": "Cabral",
                "Email": "liljorge@gmail.com",
                "Nota": "xxxx",
                Editable: false
            }
        ],            
        
      },
      methods: {

        whenclick(item) {  

        console.log(item, ':item');        
          item.Editable = true;     
         },
         whenedited(nota) {
                     
          this.nota = nota;
          this.edit = false;
                 

         },
        
    change() {
      console.log('rato em cima');
      this.myclass = 'after';
      this.pincel = 'after';
    }
       
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="container">

    <div id="title"style="text-align:center;rgb(180, 67, 67);">
        <h3>Inline edition </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="caixa"style="margin:0 auto;">
 

  <!--  <span v-show="!edit" @click="whenclick()" :class="pincel" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
         


         <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                  <tr>  
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Apelido</th>
                      <th>Email</th>  
                      <th>Nota</th>                                  
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(item, index) in list">                      
                      <td>{{item.Firstname}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Lastname}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Email}}</td> 
                      <td>

                      <span v-if="!item.Editable" :class="myclass"  v-on:mouseover= "change()"  @click="whenclick(item)">{{item.Nota}} </span>

                      <input  v-model="item.Nota" v-on:keyup.enter="whenedited(item.Nota)" v-on:blur="whenedited(item.Nota)" v-if="item.Editable" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder=""> 

                      


                      </td>                                  
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>   

  </div>
  </body>
```

Coloquei um novo atributo `Editable` em seus objetos e seto este atributo para cada objeto, ao invés de uma variável global.